# Can i access /sdcard/ in ubuntu touch?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, sd-card, nexus-4

i'm able to view ubuntu's user data from android. is it possible to view my sdcard from ubuntu ?

notes: i'm using the dual boot method explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can... i found out that the sdcard is already mounted so all i had to do was bind it to the home folder. i did this with adb so connect your phone via usb and type :

```
$adb shell
#su - phablet
$sudo mkdir ~/Mount 
$sudo mount --bind /userdata/media/0 ~/Mount
$sudo chmod 777 ~/Mount
```

and now your content are visible from the file manager in ubuntu touch. you can add it to fstab to make it mount your files automatically at boot